# What does restarting mean?

Tags: ps-vita

On my vita, I changed my username ID and I'm wondering if I have to format the memory card or just turn it on and off again?
Here is the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Your question is downvoted because you have not show any prior research effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By restarting, the PlayStation Network FAQ is explaining that **you simply have to turn off and turn on your system.** That is exactly what a “restart” is.